# start remote process and monitor status

Tags: c++, linux

I'm using Linux and C++. What is the best way to start a remote process on another machine and verify that it is still running periodically programatically? I'll need to do this for multiple processes as well. Thank you

Comment: What research have you performed? What did you struggle with specifically?

Answer (score 0):

You can use MPI Interface to communicate between the master and slaves via send and recv methods. These can be used to track the status periodically. MPI tag
can be assigned to each slave and track the response from them. More info https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Message_Passing_Interface